# How do I make Vim to ask for the password everytime I open a GPG encrypted file?

Tags: encryption, vim, gnupg

I am using the [gnupg plugin](https://github.com/jamessan/vim-gnupg) with the variable `g:GPGPreferSymmetric` set.

I save and close the .gpg file with a password and when I reopen it, it is decrypted automatically without prompting me to enter the password. How do I ensure that the password is asked everytime I open the file?

My setup -

- gVim ver 8.0
- Windows 10
- GPG4Win 3.0.3 (which consists of) -

  - GnuPG 2.2.4
  - Kleopatra 3.0.2
  - GPA 0.9.10
  - GpgOL 2.0.6
  - GpgEX 1.0.5

Comment: Why don't you ask the plugin's author? Sounds like there's missing documentation or even a missing feature!

Comment: I was unsure if it was a problem with the plugin, or a feature of this plugin/GPG or if it was a fault in my setup. I haven't used GPG before, I am working under the assumption that symmetric GPG is similar to blowfish2 in most ways except strength of encryption (i.e. GPG is stronger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this problem because [gpg-agent](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gpg-agent) was active.
Reopening the file after the 'cache-ttl' time period expired caused the prompt to enter the password to reappear.